# extension attributes for ad user in azure active directory using Microsoft.Graph

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Hi I am trying to add extension property to azure ad user using Microsoft.Graph package.

```
   var schema = new SchemaExtension()
                    {
                        Id = "Location",
                        TargetTypes = new List<string> { "User" },
                        Description = "DescribesLocation",
                        Properties = new List<ExtensionSchemaProperty>() { new ExtensionSchemaProperty { Name = "LocationCode", Type = "String" } }
                    };

                    var result = graphClient.SchemaExtensions.Request().AddAsync(schema).Result;
```

I have created a daemon application in azure ad registered applications and given below permissions to the application

1. Directory.Read.All
2. Directory.ReadWrite.All
3. User.Invite.All
4. User.Read
5. User.Read.All
6. User.ReadWrite.All
7. Group.Read.All
8. Group.ReadWrite.All

I am getting error message as Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation. What other permissions are required for this operation and which permissions are not required?

Answer (score 0):

You need the [Directory.AccessAsUser.All](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/schemaextension-post-schemaextensions?view=graph-rest-1.0) permission. Here are some [test cases](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/tests/Microsoft.Graph.DotnetCore.Test/Requests/Functional/SchemaExtensionTests.cs) that you may find useful.

Comment: I tried this but no luck. I am using Daemon application without signed in user.The console application is using app secret for authentication.

Comment: Directory.AccessAsUser.All permission comes only when you have application with Delegated permissions  in azure portal.

Comment: Any Update on this issue as I am experiencing the same.